# Javascript map function :add new key and value to object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have JSON array like this

```
var array= [{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:2,name:'bar'}]
```

I would like to add a new key (eg:`isApproved`) to each object in the existing array

expected output:

```
var array= [{id:1,name:'foo',isApproved:true},{id:2,name:'bar',isApproved:true}]
```

I used the map function to achieve this

```
array.map(function(e,index){
     e.isApproved[index]= true
}
```

But this not worked for me

Comment: You have to return it from the callback. and map returns a new array.

Comment: just add `return e` after setting the value.

Comment: But getting `Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

Comment: try `e.isApproved = true` instead using `e.isApproved[index] = true`.

Comment: `e.isApproved = true`. delete `[index]`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You were really close. You do not need the index here. The map passes through every element of the array, so 'e' will be each object in your array.

```js
var array= [{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:2,name:'bar'}];

array.map(function(e){
     e.isApproved = true;
});
          
console.log(array);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()` expects a return value from a function

Answer (score 10):

With this code, you wont mutate objects inside your array

```
const arr = [{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:2,name:'bar'}];
const mapped = arr.map(element => Object.assign(element, {isApproved: true})
```

More new approach would be using spread operator:

```
const arr = [{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:2,name:'bar'}];
const mapped = arr.map(element => ({isApproved: true ,...element}))
```

Snippet

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:2,name:'bar'}];
    const mapped = arr.map(element => ({isApproved: true ,...element}))


console.log(mapped)
```

Comment: Thanks about the spread operator, fulfilled my leant quota for the day.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you don't need the index:

```js
var array= [{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:2,name:'bar'}];

array.map(value => value.isApproved = true);
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the actual item 'e' in the map

Map also gives you the facility to alter each element and return them in a new array. This can be useful if you do not want your current array to alter its state rather you need a modified form of the same array.

check this code:

```
var array= [{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:2,name:'bar'}];

var modifiedArray = array.map(function(e,index){
    return Object.assign({isApproved:true},e);
});

console.log(array);
console.log(modifiedArray);
```

Output:

```
//array
[{id: 1, name: "foo"},
{id: 2, name: "bar"}]

//modifiedArray
[{isApproved: true, id: 1, name: "foo"},
{isApproved: true, id: 2, name: "bar"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`e[index]` doesn't make sense since this `index` is meant for the `array` you are iterating.

Set the property directly to `e`

```
array.map(function(e,index){
     e.isApproved = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

var array= [{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:2,name:'bar'}]
array.forEach(function(e,index){
     e.isApproved= true;
})
console.log(array);

</script>
```

You can use forEach instead of map.

Comment: actually, its always better to use map, if you want to modify every element of given array